# Why does \ifnum not work inside of TikZ style definitions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to write some conditional TikZ styles. This has been tried here before, but I think never in a completely satisfying way. My try is this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{drawif/.style={\ifnum 1=1 draw\else fill\fi}}
    \tikz{\node[drawif] {Test};}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `1=1`, insert a meaningful expression. When compiling, this gives a lot of errors:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
               }
l.7         \tikz{\node[drawif]
                      {Test};}
! Missing number, treated as zero.
               }
l.7         \tikz{\node[drawif]
                      {Test};}
! Argument of \pgfkeys@@normal has an extra }.
            \par 
l.7         \tikz{\node[drawif] {Test};}

Runaway argument?
\pgfkeys@mainstop \else \pgfkeys@case@two \fi \fi \fi \pgfkeys@parse \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@@normal was complete.
```

etc.
What's going on?

Comment: if you need to do the test at style definition time you could try by putting it outside the `\tikzset` command or using `.estyle`

Comment: Instead if you need the code to be executed every time you set the style you really need `.code` instead of `.style`. What happens here is that `tikz` tried to parse your code as tikz styles and gets all confused

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens is that `tikz` is trying to parse the style you are defining as a style and gets confused when it reads `\ifnum`.

What you actually want here is to run some code when setting the `drawif` style.
This code will in turn set some styles under certain conditions.
To run code when setting a style you can use the `.code` key instead of the `.style` one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{drawif/.code={\ifnum 1=1 \tikzset{draw}\else \tikzset{fill}\fi}}
    \tikz{\node[drawif] {Test};}
\end{document}
```

You can use `#1` inside the `.code` value to refer to the argument that can be passed to the style:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{drawif/.code={\ifnum #1=1 \tikzset{draw}\else \tikzset{fill}\fi}}
    \tikz{\node[drawif=1] {Test};}
\end{document}
```

and with `drawif/.default=1` you can set a default value used for `#1` in case `drawif` is used without argument.

Comment: Great, finally I have the feeling to understand how styles are being parsed!

Comment: Note that I had to use `##1` rather than `#1` ([ref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450318/181375)).

Answer (score 3):

`.style` tries to split the input at `=` to recognize key/value pairs. You need to hide the `=` sign in braces:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  drawif/.style={%
    \expandafter\ifnum\@firstofone{1=\test} draw\else fill\fi
  }
}
\makeatother

\def\test{1}
\tikz{\node[drawif] {Test};}

\def\test{0}
\tikz{\node[drawif] {Test};}

\end{document}
```

but I think the `.code` route is better.

A simpler trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\equals}{=}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  drawif/.style={%
    \ifnum 1\equals\test draw\else fill\fi
  }
}

\def\test{1}
\tikz{\node[drawif] {Test};}

\def\test{0}
\tikz{\node[drawif] {Test};}

\end{document}
```

Of course `\test` is used just for the example. Note that `<` or `>` don't give problems.

Comment: Ah it's the `=`! What about `\newcommand{\testme}[1]{\ifnum#1=1 draw\else fill\fi}
\tikzset{drawif/.style={\testme{#1}}}` then?

Comment: @Bordaigorl Also `\ifnum 1\equals 1` (where `\equals` expands to `=`).