# LaTeX error: illegal parameter number in definition of \pgffor@b

Tags: errors, foreach, loops, programming

I am trying to use a loop. The following does not work:

```
\foreach \a in {no,has}{    
    \begin{table}[H]
    \footnotesize
    \captionsetup{width=.9\linewidth}
    \caption{text}
    \vspace{-22pt}
    \label{}
    \begin{center}
    {
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
    \toprule \toprule \\
    ~~~~text \\
    \hline
    \input{../text1_\a_c.tex}
    \hline \\
    ~~~~text \\
    \hline
    \input{../text2_\a_c.tex}
    \hline
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{center}
    \caption*{\begin{footnotesize}  \end{footnotesize}}
    \end{table}
}
```

What I am trying to do is to access four similarly-named files with the loop — two the first time through (named ...no...) and two the second time through (named ...has...).

I get this error:

```
illegal parameter number in definition of \pgffor@b
```

Note that the following *does* work:

This works:

```
\foreach \a in {no,has}{
\a
}
```

What should I try to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367979/latex-foreach-in-tabular-environment

Comment: Btw, filenames with underscores in them are problematic in latex... Renaming them as `text2-\a-c.tex` might solve your problem. If not rather using `\foreach` from [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package you'll probably have more luck with `\docsvlist` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the definition of `\sym` occurs in the argument to another command, it should be

```
\def\sym##1{\ifmmode^{##1}\else\(^{##1}\)\fi}
```

in this code.

Comment: The other command that the definition of ```\sym``` occurs in is the ```\foreach``` command? I'm confused, I only knew that adding additional ```#``` is necessary if defining a macro inside the replacement text of another macro, why is it also needed when passing a marco definition as an argument when executing another macro?

Comment: @AndiBauer That's more complicated and would require an analysis of what `\foreach` does.

Comment: Ok but you're saying that (for some reason) whenever I'm defining a macro inside a ```\foreach``` loop, I need to add the extra ```#```, right?

Comment: @AndiBauer Yes, I guess so.